# How do I merge all the cases into One?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

```
private void makeMoleVisable(int mole, PictureBox MoleHill)
    {
        switch (mole)
        {
            case 1:
                if (p01.Image == pmiss.Image && MoleHill.Image == pHill.Image)
                {
                    molesmissed ++;
                }
                p01.Image = MoleHill.Image;
              break;
            case 2:
              if (p02.Image == pmiss.Image && MoleHill.Image == pHill.Image)
              {
                  molesmissed++;
              }
                p02.Image = MoleHill.Image;
                break;
```

** I have 36 of these case statements each one for another for a different picture box; how do I group them all into one case statement so my code can be more efficient**

Comment: People have expressed this below, but how about passing the picture object (i.e. p01, p02) as an argument to the function, and "foreach" mole picture calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        string ControlIdSuffix = mole < 10 ? "0" : "" + mole.ToString();
        Control[] picBoxes = this.Controls.Find("p" + ControlIdSuffix, true);
        if (picBoxes.Length > 0)
        {
            PictureBox p = picBoxes[0] as PictureBox;
            if (p != null) {
               if (p.Image == pmiss.Image && MoleHill.Image == pHill.Image)
                  molesMissed++;
               p.Image = MoleHill.Image;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Consider this about your first line: (ex) `1.ToString("00") -> "01"`

Answer (score 9):

It looks like your case is used to select an image, then you always apply the same processing to the image.

How about storing the image in a List or Dictionary, use the `mole` value to retrieve the correct image, then process that image?

Something like

```
Dictionary<int, PictureBox> images;
var image = images[mole];
// do stuff to image
```

If the images are all numbered sequentially, a List is slightly more efficient.  Remember that list indices are 0 based.  If you number your images from 1 as seems to be the case from your `switch` statement (*assumed in the following example*), remember to adjust accordingly.

```
List<PictureBox> images;
int index = mole - 1; // Assumes mole starts with 1, so adjust to 0-based index
var image = images[index];
```

Comment: And roll through the moles in a `for` loop.

Comment: They look to be all sequential integer keys, so a `List` would make more sense than a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Yes, they well could be.  I mention `List` as a candidate data structure in my answer but went with `Dictionary` in the code sample because I did not want to make that assumption.

Comment: @Servy: Updated to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

The thing that differs in the `switch` is the pN variable. Instead of putting those objects in discrete variables, create an array you can index into:

```
var p = new [] { p01, p02, .... }
```

And then your code can look like this:

```
if (p[mole-1].Image == pmiss.Image && MoleHill.Image == pHill.Image)
{
    molesmissed ++;
}
p[mole-1].Image = MoleHill.Image
```

Comment: ...possibly with a little bounds checking for safety.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your PictureBoxes into a list and then access them by index:

```
List<PictureBox> pbs = new List<PictureBox>();
foreach(Control c in this.Controls) if( c is PictureBox ) pbs.Add( (PictureBox)c );

private void MakeMoleVisible(Int32 mole) {
    pbs[ mole ] = // whatever
}
```

Comment: Looks like `mole` may be 1-based, in which case offset to the list index may be needed.

Comment: `pbs.AddRange(this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>());`  if you're going for a one-liner when defining the list instead of cramming 3 into 1.